# edittext is focused but cursor is not visible

Tags: android, focus, cursor, android-edittext

i want to enter a text in an edittext and when i click on enter key of keyboard(physical/soft)the text should be added to list and edittext will be cleared to make next entry.but here the edittext is getting cleared but it loses the focus. But edittext.isFocused() function returns true. Cursor is not visible in the edittext.code is pasted below.please help me.

```
 edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView tv, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event != null)
                    && (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN))
                return false;

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText().toString()
                        .trim())) {
                    makeFreeFormTextItem((edittext.getText().toString()
                            .trim()));
                    edittext.setText("");
                    edittext.requestFocus();
                    edittext.setCursorVisible(true);
                    return true;
            }
               }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: seems onEditorAction() is incomplete. Do You return true in case if cleared text?

Comment: tried Your code on 4.0 Android with two EditText and it works as expected (only commented line is makeFreeFormTextItem()). After pressing enter I'm able to observe focus retain on the first edit.

Comment: but in my case it is not working....

Comment: have You tried it without list?